# Why are my calculations off?

Tags: c++, class, compiler-construction, unresolved-external, lnk

I'm practically done with this program. My only issue is my calculations, I guess. My numbers are completely off. I am too new to post an image, so here is the link to my output. Example: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/62/16902078.jpg/

NumDays.h

```
#ifndef NUMDAYS_H
#define NUMDAYS_H
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class NumDays
{
private:
    double hours, days;
    void calcDays();
public:
    // Constructors
    NumDays();
    NumDays(double);
    // Mutator Functions
    void setHours(double);

    // Accessor Functions
    double getHours();
    double getDays();

    // Overloaded operator functions
    NumDays operator + (const NumDays &);   // Overloaded +
    NumDays operator - (const NumDays &);   // Overloaded -
    NumDays operator ++ ();                 // Overloaded Prefix ++
    NumDays operator ++ (int);              // Overloaded Postfix ++
    NumDays operator -- ();                 // Overloaded Prefix --
    NumDays operator -- (int);              // Overloaded Postfix --

};
#endif
```

NumDays.cpp

```
// Implementation file for the NumDays class
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "NumDays.h"
using namespace std;

// Recalculation function
void NumDays::calcDays()
{
    days = hours / 8;
}

// Default Constructor
NumDays::NumDays()
{
    hours = 0;
    days = 0;
}

// Constructor 1
NumDays::NumDays(double h)
{
    hours = h;         
    days = hours * 1 / 8;   
}


// Mutatory Functions
void NumDays::setHours(double h)
{
    hours = h;
}


// Accessor Functions
double NumDays::getHours()
{
    return hours;
}

double NumDays::getDays()
{
    NumDays::calcDays();
    return days;
}


// Overloaded operator functions
NumDays NumDays::operator + (const NumDays &a)
{
    NumDays temp;
    temp.hours = this->hours + a.hours;
return temp;
}

NumDays NumDays::operator - (const NumDays &a)
{
    NumDays temp;
    temp.hours = this->hours + a.hours;
    return temp;
}


NumDays NumDays::operator ++ ()
{
    ++hours;
    calcDays();
    return *this;
}

NumDays NumDays::operator -- ()
{
    --hours;
    calcDays();
    return *this;
}

NumDays NumDays::operator ++ (int)
{
    NumDays temp(*this);
    ++hours;
    return temp;
}

NumDays NumDays::operator -- (int)
{
    hours--;
    calcDays();
    return *this;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "NumDays.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double hours1, hours2;

    //Prompt for the data for the first 2 objects
    cout << "Enter the number of hours for the the object called One: ";
    cin >> hours1;
    cout << "Enter the number of hours for the the object called Two: ";
    cin >> hours2;

    // Define two objects of WorkHours
    NumDays one(hours1), two(hours2);

    cout << "One: " << one.getDays() << " day(s)" << endl;
    cout << "Two: " << two.getDays() << " day(s)" << endl << endl;

    // Demonstrate addition and subtraction operators
    cout << "Three = One + Two: " << (one - two).getDays() << " day(s)" << endl;
    cout << "One - Two: " << (one - two).getDays() << " day(s)" << endl << endl;

    // Define a third and fourth object to be used for further operator demonstrations
    NumDays three(one + two), four;

    // Demonstrate increment and decrement operators
    four = three++;
    cout << "Four = Three++ " << endl;
    cout << " Three: " << three.getDays() << " day(s)" << endl;
    cout << " Four: " << four.getDays() << " day(s)" << endl << endl;

    four = ++three;
    cout << "Four = ++Three: " << endl;
    cout << " Three: " << three.getDays() << " day(s)" << endl;
    cout << " Four: " << four.getDays() << " day(s)" << endl << endl;

    four = three--;
    cout << "Four = Three--: " << endl;
    cout << " Three: " << three.getDays() << " day(s)" << endl;
    cout << " Four: " << four.getDays() << " day(s)" << endl << endl;

    four = --three;
    cout << "Four = --Three: " << endl;
    cout << " Three: " << three.getDays() << " day(s)" << endl;
    cout << " Four: " << four.getDays() << " day(s)" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code to only the relevant lines. SO frowns on walls of text.

Answer (score 2):

So, where is the implementation of your `operator <<` function?

The code you posted contains none. You declared it as a friend in `NumDays.h`

```
friend ostream &operator << (ostream &, NumDays &);
```

but there's no definition for it either in `NumDays.cpp` or anywhere else.

Obviously, the linker is telling you that it can't find it. Neither can I.

You have to go to your `NumDays.cpp` and **implement** your operators `<<` and `>>` there

```
ostream &operator << (ostream &s, NumDays &n)
{
  // Whatever
  return s;
}

istream &operator >> (istream &s, NumDays &n);
{
  // Whatever
  return s;
}
```

Comment: Alright, so I added in these lines to NumDays.h:

    class NumDays; // Forward declaration
    
    //Function Prototype for Overloaded Stream Operators
    ostream &operator << (ostream &, const NumDays &);
    istream &operator >> (istream &, NumDays &);

It still gives the same error. Not sure what else to do.

I'm also not sure how to format a reply on this site, so if it's possible, I apologize.

Comment: @slickster you always can edit your question to add more details

Comment: I did. I edited my original post to reflect my changes. Thanks.

Comment: @slickster: I don't understand why you did this. You added extra*declarations*. You don't need more declarations. You have enough already. What you need is *definitions*. You have to **define** these operators, i.e. you have to **implement** them. As functions. You have to give them *bodies* that actually do what you want them to do. You have already done this for all of your operators in `NumDays.cpp`. Just do the same thing for `<<` and `>>` operators and that's it.

Comment: @slickster: Your latest additions to `NumDays.h` are completely unnecessary. Your `NumDays.h` was perfectly fine in its original form. You just need to **define** `<<` and `>>`. And it should probably be done in `NumDays.cpp`

Comment: Updated everything. Turns out I didn't even need that part of the code. =\